# direction of division operation on integer in c

Tags: c

Does the output of the code given below depends on the compiler or it is guaranteed to be same for all the compilers?

```
int main()
{ 
    int i=5;
    i=i/3;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about this suggests to you that it might be compiler dependent? Also, this code has no output except compile errors ;) (check your string in the `printf()` call).

Comment: main.c|7|error: stray '\' in program|  (compled with GCC 4.4.1)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "direction of division".

Comment: @Vaughn: Guessing he means "direction of rounding". Valid question, IMO...

Comment: Integer division always returns the integer part of the fraction and is always guaranteed to round down, even for negative numbers (e.g. `-5/3 == -2`), at least on x86.

Comment: @HristoIliev Nope, integer division truncates towards zero in C.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Hristo: Actually, it depends.  See my answer!

Comment: I stand corrected - `IDIV` rounds negatives towards zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour of your example is well-defined.

However, in the case of negative values, it is less clear.  Pre-C99, whether integer division was rounded towards zero or towards negative infinity was left as implementation-defined:

> If either operand is negative, whether the
>   result of the `/` operator is the largest integer less than the
>   algebraic quotient or the smallest integer greater than the algebraic
>   quotient is implementation-defined

C99 mandates rounding towards zero:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any
>   fractional part discarded..

Answer (score 1):

[The C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), Section 6.5.5, Paragraph 6:

> When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded. If the
>   quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall
>   equal a.

The standard also notes that this is commonly called "truncation towards zero".

So yes, it is well-defined.